# pgf/tikz with genealogytree and the 'before upper' setting for boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, pgfkeys, genealogytree, genealogy

```
\documentclass{standalone} %or standalone
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{info separators={\par}{. }{}{}} %no period after comment

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \genealogytree[
                processing=fit,
                level distance=1cm,
                level size=1.5cm,
                node size from=2cm to 4cm,
                box clear,
                box={enhanced,fit basedim=8pt,
                        halign=center,valign=center,
                        before upper={\parskip 0.15\tcbfitdim plus 0pt minus 0pt},
                        drop fuzzy shadow
                },
                database content interpreter,
                database format=full,
                list separators hang,
                edges=rounded,
                date format=dd.mm.yyyy]{
                parent{
                        g[female]{
                                female,
                                name = {Name \surn{Long Surname}},
                                birth- = {1865-10-08},
                                death- = {1945-08-20},
                                comment = {born NameWithfxx},
                        }
                }
        }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with that I get this:

[image: f in comment, with before upper option]

this is bad since I don't know why exactly more space is left on the left and right and the font is smaller.

If I now replace the character 'f' in the comment by an 'r' I get this:

[image: r in comment, with before upper option]

which is really weird since what characters I use shouldn't matter in this way (I tried it with other characters too, some seem to be working, some not).

I tried some things and finally I got that if I remove the "before upper" option of the boxes I get this with the r

[image: r in comment, without upper option]

and this with the f

[image: f in comment, without before upper option].

Does anyone have an Idea why it is that way, why does it matter which character is used and what does the "before upper" option do? (I just took it from the signpost template and wasn't able to find what the option does on the internet)

EDIT: Figured finally out that the before upper option (`before upper={\parskip 0.15\tcbfitdim plus 0pt minus 0pt},`) is processed by tcolorbox (the given code is placed after the color and font settings but before the content). But I still don't know why this conflicts with characters like f,g or q

Comment: A difference is that the "f" goes under the line so it takes up more space vertically.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that fits with my experience that this phenomena occurs with the character 'q' as well.

Comment: Remains the question what this option ("before upper") does and why it helps

Comment: I figured out the box option of genealogytree is processed by tcolorbox. So I finally found the "before upper" option in the tcorbox documentation.

Now my problem is that I'm too dumb to unterstand what `\parskip 0.15\tcbfitdim plus 0pt minus 0pt` does or moreover what the problem with that is (in the cases with the character f and q f.e.)

Comment: Well the line sets the spacing according to the font size. Where this spacing is used I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1: Allow variable node width and font size shrinking. Slightly enlarge the `level size=1.5cm` to, for example `level size=1.6cm`, to handle the specific situation (`f` causes font shrinking).

Solution 2: Allow variable node height with the cost of fixed node width and fixed font size. (see below)

#### Explanation

It is the total height of node `g[female]` that matters. Here the "node" is a `genealogytree` concept and is different from the `tikz` node.

Initially, `genealogytree` sets option `timeflow=down`. This fixes the height of every node to `level size`, and let option `node size from` sets the range of node width. If the natural height or width of node is larger than the fixed height or minimum width, respectively, `genealogytree` tries to firstly enlarge the width. If maximum width (with fixed height) is still not big enough, then font size is shrunk, using `fitting` library of `tcolorbox`.

In your example,

- `level size=1.5cm` and `node size from=2cm to 4cm` sets the node size;
- by setting `\gtrset{info separators={\par}{. }{}{}}`, the node content is split into four paragraphs, joined by three vertical skip `\parskip`;
- by setting `before upper={\parskip=0.15\tcbfitdim plus 0pt minus 0pt}`, `\parskip` is set, at the beginning of node content, to be variable with font size. Here `\tcbfitdim` represents the used font size set by `fitting` library of `tcolorbox`. (By setting `fit basedim=8pt`, `\tcbfitdim` starts from `8pt`).
- Here comes the most tricky part: the `f` (with a depth) in `comment = {born NameWithfxx}` makes the natural (total) height of node slightly bigger than 1.5cm, which causes node width enlarging. But even using maximum width will not solve the too-high problem, font size is then shrunk (with the maximum width applied). This makes the output of `f` and `r` differs in two ways: the node width and the font size. But these differences has a same cause.
- The change to `\parskip` is nothing more than adding vertical spaces and making the node higher.

---

Some examples to show how tricky it is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} %or standalone
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{info separators={\par}{. }{}{}} %no period after comment

\begin{document}

\newcommand\testGTree[3][]{
  \par
  \parbox{20em}{\texttt{%
    \detokenize{\parindent= #2} ... \\
    comment = \detokenize{#3}
  }}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \genealogytree[
      processing=fit,
      level distance=1cm,
      level size=1.5cm,
      node size from=2cm to 4cm,
      box clear,
      box={enhanced,fit basedim=8pt,
        halign=center,valign=center,
        before upper={\parskip=#2 plus 0pt minus 0pt},
        drop fuzzy shadow
      },
      database content interpreter,
      database format=full,
      list separators hang,
      edges=rounded,
      date format=dd.mm.yyyy,
      #1] 
    {
      parent{
        g[id=xxx]{
          female,
          name = {Name \surn{Long Surname}},
          birth- = {1865-10-08},
          death- = {1945-08-20},
          comment = {#3\smash{, \the\tcbfitdim}},
        }
      }
    }
    \draw (0, 0) grid (4, .1); % to measure node width
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par
}

\parindent=0pt
\paragraph{Group 1} zero \verb|\parindent| is ok
\testGTree{0pt}{f}
\testGTree{0pt}{r}

\paragraph{Group 2} \verb|\parindent=.8pt ...| is enough to trigger width enlarging and font size shrinking
\testGTree{.8pt}{f}
\testGTree{.8pt}{r}

\paragraph{Group 3} with \verb|\parindent=0.15\tcbfitdim ...|, depth \verb|0.2pt| is enough to trigger.

\newlength{\charDepth}
\newcommand{\showDepth}[1]{%
  \settodepth\charDepth{#1}%
  #1\smash{, \the\charDepth}
}

\testGTree{0.15\tcbfitdim}{\showDepth f}
\testGTree{0.15\tcbfitdim}{\showDepth r}
\testGTree{0.15\tcbfitdim}{r \rule[-.2pt]{1pt}{5pt}}

\paragraph{Group 4} a slightly larger \verb|level size=1.6cm| fixes the original problem.
\testGTree[level size=1.6cm]{0pt}{f}
\testGTree[level size=1.6cm]{0pt}{r}
\end{document}
```

#### Solution 2

Result: fix node width and let node height change by content. Restricted by the package implementation, you cannot have both width and height variable.

Main change: use `tcolorbox` option `natural height`. Search `natural height` in doc of `genealogytree` to see more examples.

Changes in detail:

- Add option `natural height` inside `box={...}`.
- Change `processing=fit` to `processing=tcolorbox`, to allow variable node height. Also add `size=title` inside `box={...}` to set tcolorbox margins.
- Adjust `node size` to some appropriate value. This would be used as the fixed node width.
- Replace useless `fitting` related options. Inside `box={...}`,

  - replace `fit basedim=8pt` by `fontupper=\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont`
  - replace `0.15\tcbfitdim` used in `before upper={...}` by `1.2pt` (`8pt * 0.15`).

[image: variable node height]

```
\documentclass{article} %or standalone
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{info separators={\par}{. }{}{}} %no period after comment

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \genealogytree[
      processing=tcolorbox,
      level distance=1cm,
      level size=1.5cm,
      node size=3cm,
      box clear,
      box={enhanced, 
        fontupper=\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont,
        halign=center, valign=center, size=title,
        % 1.2pt = 8pt * 0.15
        before upper={\parskip=1.2pt plus 0pt minus 0pt},
        drop fuzzy shadow,
        natural height
      },
      database content interpreter,
      database format=full,
      list separators hang,
      edges=rounded,
      date format=dd.mm.yyyy] 
  {
    parent{
      g[id=xxx]{
        female,
        name = {Name \surn{Long Surname}},
        birth- = {1865-10-08},
        death- = {1945-08-20},
        comment = {born NameWithfxx},
      }
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I already was a bit desperate since I didn't know how to fix it. For me as a beginner its very difficult to understand/see connections like this since so many packages (I don't know that well yet) different from the one you initially use (genealogytree) are internally used.

Comment: Is there a way to make this more general so that everywhere the same fontsize is used (i.e. allowing the height to be more dynamic)?

Comment: @atticus 1) Using latex is not always so difficult. You just encountered a deep  dependence package relations. Say, `genealogytree` relies `tcolorbox`, and `tcolorbox` relies `tikz`, and the latter in each pair is more complicated than the former. This is a (very) rare case. 2) I have added a no-font-shrink example.

Comment: `Using latex is not always so difficult.` Yes I know, as a matter of facts it is easy after the first short time, but only the normal things not something like this where you have to handle that much big packages (espacially pgf/tikz is not that easy). Would you just shortly point out what option are (at least for tcolorbox) obsolete after that change? (so that one could experiment a bit)

Comment: @atticus Answer updated. `fit fontdim` is still usefull.

Comment: So only options are added. Ok, then a big thank you to you is there anything I can do? ( think no ;)

Comment: @atticus Happy LaTeXing :)

Comment: @atticus With variable node height, `fit basedim` __is__ not used and the node font is 10pt, not 8pt. I have updated my answer to add a `\fontsize`.